# Repeating values on map:leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to make a map using leaflet. I uploaded a shapefile of 216 districts. I also have a dataset with information from 7 out the 216 districts.

I was hoping for the map to have districts that don't have values or 0%  in grey saying not enough information". While having districts with actual values (>0%) showing up as colour following their corresponding bins.

When I tried to do upload my dataset and shapfile, I got a map with coloured districts everywhere. Based on my dataset, there are suppose to be 4 districts (>0%) in colour. But this is not what I see on my map.

How do I make sure that only the districts in my dataset light up where it is suppose to light up, without repeating all over the map? (while maintaining the backdrop of all the other districts in grey)

So far this is the code I used to achieved the map:

```
districtsg <-readOGR("sample/copyfile/Districts/Map_of_Districts_.shp")

districtsg <- sp::spTransform(districtsg, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

wpnew <- wpnew [order(match(wpnew$District,districtsg$NAME)),]


bins <- c(0.1,2.0,5.0,10.0,25.0,40.0,50.0)
pal<- colorBin("YlOrRd",domain=wpnew$per.content,bins=bins)


m<- leaflet() %>%
   setView(lng = -1.0232,lat=7.9465,zoom = 6) %>%
   addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
   addPolygons(data =districtsg,
               weight = 1,
               smoothFactor = 0.5,
               color = "White",
               fillOpacity = 0.8,
               fillColor= ~pal(wpnew$per.content),
               highlight = highlightOptions(
                  weight = 5,
                  color = "#666666",
                  dashArray = "",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,
                  bringToFront  = TRUE
               ))
m


labels <- paste(  "<p>","District:", districtsg$NAME,"</p>",
                  "<p>", "% of reports that are content:",round(wpnew$per.content,digits = 3),"</p>",
                  "<p>", "Total reports labelled as a content:",round(wpnew$totalcontent,digits = 3),"</p>",
                  "<p>", "Total  reports from this district:",round(wpnew$totalreports,digits = 3),"</p>",sep = "" )

m<- leaflet() %>%
   setView(lng = -1.0232,lat=7.9465,zoom = 6) %>%
   addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
   addPolygons(data =districtsg,
               weight = 1,
               smoothFactor = 0.5,
               color = "White",
               fillOpacity = 0.8,
               fillColor= pal(wpnew$per.content),
               label = lapply(labels,HTML)) %>%
   addLegend(pal=pal,
             values = wpnew$per.content,
             opacity = 0.7,
             "topright")
m
```

```
    districts      totalreports     totalcontent           per.content
1   Jomoro              4               2                   50.00000
2   Ellembelle          2               1                   50.00000
3   Tarkwa Nsuaem       1               0                    0.00000
4   Bia West            1               0                    0.00000
5   Bodi                2               0                    0.00000
6   Accra Metropolis    3               1                   33.33333
7   Adenta              3               1                   33.33333
```

shapefile can be downloaded here:

https://data.gov.gh/dataset/shapefiles-all-districts-ghana-2012-216-districts

Comment: I am not able to access your data source, but I work with school district data and would be happy to help with a better idea of the dataset.

Comment: Hi Susan,   My data set comes from a sample survey. In my dataset, there are 7 people in 7 different districts. My shape file has 216 districts in total. I am looking to have 4 districts in my sample that have values greater than 0 in the percent content column to show up on the leaftlet map. Right now, I see several districts lit up when in reality there are suppose to be only 4 that are lit up. I hope I gave the information you need.Let me know If you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handling the joining of shape file and the data file differently and I create my base map using tmap. but perhaps this will be helpful.

```
library(rgdal)
library(tmap)
library(leaflet)

####Access shape map
elem <- readOGR(dsn = "Data/P3Map", layer = "Boundary___ES")

####Preschool Status for Elementary Schools####
schoolAdresses_PK_2021 <- read_excel("Data/P3Map/schoolAdresses_PK_2021.xlsx") %>% 
  mutate(PreK= factor(PreK)) %>% 
  clean_names("lower_camel") %>% 
  mutate(programType = factor(programType))

##### Merge shape with PreK info######
map <- merge(elem, by.x = "ES_Name", schoolAdresses_PK_2021, by.y = "esName" )


#### Render Map####

 MyColors <- c('#e2a331', '#d3d3d3','#3688c8')  #yellow, #grey, #blue

    PKMap <- tm_shape(map)+
      tm_fill(col="preK",
              title = " ",
              palette = MyColors)+
      tm_shape(JeffcoMap)+
      tm_borders(col = "white")+
      tm_layout("Jeffco PreK Expansion 2019-2020", legend.text.size = -0.5)+
      tm_text(text = "ES_ShortNa", size = 0.5, group = "Site Names") 

    PKMap %>%  tmap_leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = -105.10033, lat = 39.6, zoom =9) %>% #lat and long of my district
      addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldGrayCanvas', group='Grayscale Map') %>% 
      addProviderTiles('OpenStreetMap', group='Street Map') %>%
      addMarkers(lng = -105.155927, #add marker for PK detached from elementary
                 lat = 39.746347, 
                 icon = YellowIcon, 
                 label = "Litz", 
                 popup = "<b>Program type:</b><br>Ext. Day", 
                 popupOptions = labelOptions(direction = "bottom",
                                             textsize = "8px"),
                 group = "Stand alone PreK")
```

from here you can add leaflet layers

It's tough without your data, but I hope this is helpful. In my case, I am mapping 95 elementary schools in one district.

Your 'districtsg' = My 'elem'

Your 'wpnew' = My 'map'

Example map

[image]

Here is my attempt while using your datasets:

```
library(rgdal)
library(tmap)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)


districtsg <-readOGR('data/Map_of_Districts_216.shp')
wpnew <- read.csv('data/dataFromStack.csv') 

map <- sp::merge(x = districtsg, y = wpnew, by = "NAME")


MyColors <- c('#e2a331', '#d3d3d3','#3688c8')  #yellow, #grey, #blue

 tm_shape(map)+
  tm_fill(col="totalcontent",
          title = " ",
          palette = MyColors)+
  tm_shape(districtsg)+
  tm_borders(col = "white")
```

Here is the result that I get.. It does take a moment to render in the R Studio Viewer

[image]

Comment: Hi Susan, I updated my question to provide dataset and shapefile. If you have time and would like to help given more information, I'ld appreciate it.  I am looking through your answer and I have more questions: is layout coming from the schoolAdresses_PK_2021 as well as "PreK"?

Comment: Hi Susan, this is exactly what I was looking for. I tried using the code you provided but I keep getting error when trying to merge.Error in .local(x, y, ...) : non-unique matches detected.   Did you already create "map" prior?

Comment: Ah, I forgot. I created another column in the wpnew dataframe called NAME to match the column in the spatial file. So I have, essentially, duplicated column one, districts, in your wpnew

Comment: Thank you Suzanne, i was able to get the same map as you. I want to be able to add more information to what is seem when hover on the district.Where are add my input? Lastly, where can I change legend information

Comment: There are several options for controlling the legend in the tm_layout and tm_fill documentation

Comment: You can pass the map object that you created with tmap to tmap_leaflet to addPopups():    districtMap <- tmap_leaflet() %>%  addPopups()